# Adobe AIR Simulator displays wrong size

Tags: actionscript-3, air, screen, simulator, starling-framework

I'm currently developing a Game via Starling and AS3.

I came across a wierd issue. My Simulator does not display the full stage.
Image for better explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoMzt.png

I tested around a bit and i found out that a Quad with a 775 height fills the whole height of a 800 stageHeight. Why is it like that? There should be a 25 space.

Is this because i am running on mac and the window displays it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //this is the size used to test NOT the device size
        var widthDevelop:int = yourStageWidth; 
        //Example var widthDevelop:int = 480; 


        var screenWidth:int  = stage.stageWidth;
        var screenHeight:int = stage.stageHeight;

        var viewPort:Rectangle = RectangleUtil.fit(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, widthDevelop, screenHeight*(widthDevelop/screenWidth)),
        new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight),
        ScaleMode.NO_BORDER);
        this._starling.viewPort = viewPort;
        this._starling.stage.stageWidth = widthDevelop;
        this._starling.stage.stageHeight = screenHeight*(widthDevelop/screenWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks im gonna use that for testing